# How to get Formik error messages to align with input box?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, formik, chakra-ui

[image: So I have this sign up page I'm making, I used Formik to add these error messages but they are not aligning with the input box.]

How do I get these messages to align with the input boxes? I'm not sure how I could style this?
The Formik exists outside of the ReactJS return so I can't put it in a  and style. And what is the reason that the error message is aligning to the edge of the box anyways? I'm new to React and Formik is what was recommended in the Chakra UI Docs to use for form handling.
Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, Box } from '@chakra-ui/react'
import { Input } from "@chakra-ui/input"
import { Button } from "@chakra-ui/button";
import { FormControl, FormLabel, FormErrorMessage } from "@chakra-ui/form-control";
import { Heading, VStack } from "@chakra-ui/layout";
import { useFormik } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import "../Signup.css";
import SignupLogo from '../assets/Shots.jpg';

const Signup = () => {

    // Formik Hook to validate password and username length
    const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
            username: "",
            email: "",
            password: ""
        },
        validationSchema: Yup.object({
            username: Yup.string().required("Username Required").min(6, "Username much be minimum of 6 characters long, username too short! "),
            password: Yup.string().required("Password Required").min(8, "Password much be minimum of 5 characters long, password too short! "),
        }),
        onSubmit: (values, actions) => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 3));
            actions.resetForm();
        }
    });

    return (
        <body className='SignupImg'>
            <VStack
            as="form"
            mx="auto"
            w={{ base: "75%", md: 500 }}
            h="100vh"
            justifyContent="center"
            onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}
            className='winterCitrus'>
                
                    <Heading color="#421413">
                        Sign Up!
                    </Heading>

                    {/* Form for Username */}
                    <FormControl py={3} id="user_id" isInvalid={formik.errors.username && formik.touched.username}>
                        <FormLabel colorScheme="black">
                            <Text color="#932D30" textAlign="center">
                                Username
                            </Text>
                        </FormLabel>
                        <Input 
                        bg="white" 
                        textColor="black" 
                        name='username' 
                        placeholder="enter username" 
                        {...formik.getFieldProps("username")}
                        width={"300px"}
                        />
                        <FormErrorMessage>{formik.errors.username}</FormErrorMessage>
                    </FormControl>


                    {/* Form for Email */}
                    <FormControl py={3} id="email_id">
                        <FormLabel>
                            <Text color="#932D30" textAlign="center">
                                Email
                            </Text>
                        </FormLabel>
                        <Input 
                        bg="white" 
                        textColor="black" 
                        name='email' 
                        placeholder='enter email' 
                        onChange={formik.handleChange} 
                        value={formik.values.email}
                        width={"300px"}
                        />
                    </FormControl>

                    {/* Form for Password */}
                    <FormControl py={3} id="password_id" isInvalid={formik.errors.password && formik.touched.password}>
                        <FormLabel>
                            <Text color="#932D30" textAlign="center">
                                Password
                            </Text>
                        </FormLabel>
                        <Input 
                        bg="white" 
                        textColor="black" 
                        name='password' 
                        placeholder='enter password' 
                        {...formik.getFieldProps("password")} 
                        width={"300px"}
                        />
                        <FormErrorMessage>{formik.errors.password}</FormErrorMessage>
                    </FormControl>

                    <Button type='submit' variant="outline" bgColor="#421413">
                        Create Account
                    </Button>
            </VStack>
        </body>
            

    )
};

export default Signup;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use something like this in your code for example

```
{formik.touched.username && formik.errors.username && (
   <span className='error'>{formik.errors.username}</span>
)}
```

You could try MUI. they have dedicated docs for formik and yup